# permissions goes wrong after running php bin/magento setup:di:compile command

Tags: magento2

Every time I ran php bin/magento setup:di:compile command it gives me this error

> Class Baianat\biusers\Controller\Index\Baianat\biusers\Model\UserFactory does not exist
> Class Baianat\biusers\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory
> permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- t
> he requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only.

and then all the permissions goes wrong.
Magento 2.4.3

Comment: if you are getting this on give proper permissions for folder using command `chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/`

Comment: it didn't work.
I already gave permissions before.

Comment: run command by the root user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was

> the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only.

so I fixed my class.